# Interpreting the edges in the Serre spectral sequence

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, spectral-sequences

Let $F \hookrightarrow E \stackrel{\pi}{\rightarrow} B$ be a fiber bundle.  For simplicity, assume that $F$ is connected, that $B$ is $1$-connected, and that $B$ is a CW complex.  Consider the Serre spectral sequence
$$E^2_{pq} = H_p(B;H_q(F)) \Rightarrow H_{p+q}(E).$$
By our assumptions, we have that
$$E^2_{p0} = H_p(B) \quad \text{and} \quad E^2_{0q} = H_q(F).$$
I'd like to understand the terms $E^r_{p0}$ and $E^r_{0q}$ for $r \geq 2$.  Each $E^{r+1}_{p0}$ is a subgroup of $E^r_{p0}$ and each $E^{r+1}_{0q}$ is a quotient of $E^r_{0q}$, so what we have are
$$H_p(B) = E^2_{p0} \supset E^3_{p0} \supset E^4_{p0} \supset \cdots \supset E^{p+1}_{p0} = E^{\infty}_{p0}$$
and
$$H_q(F) = E^2_{0q} \twoheadrightarrow E^3_{0q} \twoheadrightarrow E^4_{0q} \twoheadrightarrow \cdots \twoheadrightarrow E^{q+2}_{0q} = E^{\infty}_{0q}.$$
Now, one thing I know is that
$$E^{\infty}_{p0} = E^{p+1}_{p0} = \text{Image}(H_p(E) \rightarrow H_p(B))$$
and that
$$E^{\infty}_{0q} = E^{q+2}_{0q} = \text{Image}(H_q(F) \rightarrow H_q(E)).$$
Based on these known terms and the construction of the spectral sequence, my guess is that $E^r_{p0}$ and $E^r_{0q}$ are as follows.  Let $B^{(k)}$ denote the $k$-skeleton of $B$ and let $E_k = \pi^{-1}(B^{(k)})$.

- I suspect that $E^r_{p0}$ is the image of $H_p(E,E_{p-r})$ in $H_p(B,B^{(p-r)})$, which for $r \geq 2$ is the same as $H_p(B)$.  For $r = p+1$, we have $E_{p-r} = \emptyset$, so as we want this says that $E^{\infty}_{p0} = E^{p+1}_{p0}$ is the image of $H_p(E)$ in $H_p(B)$.
- I suspect that $E^r_{0q}$ is the image of $H_q(E_0)$ in $H_q(E_{r-1})$.  To make sense of this, note that $E_0$ is the disjoint union of copies of $F$ indexed over the $0$-cells of $B$, and that the image of $H_q(E_0)$ in $H_q(E_1)$ is exactly $H_q(F)$.  This uses the fact that $B$ is $1$-connected, so the action of $\pi_1(B)$ on $H_q(F)$ is trivial.  For $r=q+2$, we have that $H_q(E_{r-1}) = H_q(E)$, so as we want this says that $E^{\infty}_{0q} = E^{q+2}_{0q}$ is the image of $H_q(F)$ in $H_q(E)$.

**Question**: Are these guesses correct, and if so what is a good reference for them?

Comment: Why not just read a textbook reference for this material, such as Spanier?

Comment: This question belongs on math.stackexchange.com, I think.

Comment: @RyanBudney: Huh?  I've got Spanier right here, and I don't think this question is answered in it.  I've looked at tons of sources, and many give the interpretations of $E^{\infty}_{p0}$ and $E^{\infty}_{0q}$ that I list but none seem to deal with the other pages.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri: Isn't that where people go to cheat on their abstract algebra homework?

Comment: The question isn't literally answered in a theorem, but if you think about how the Serre spectral sequence is defined, i.e. what the filtration is that defines the spectral sequence, you can work out the answer.

Comment: @RyanBudney: I think you and I have different ideas about what is trivial and what isn't.  The class I taught last semester included the construction of the Serre spectral sequence, so I think I understand it reasonably well.  But a few hours of playing around with the algebra this morning did not yield the terms I was looking for (which I need for a calculation I'm trying to do).  I could just be an idiot, but I like to think I'm not.

Comment: I suggest reading the guidelines to this forum, and the MSE forum that you are so eager to disrespect publicly.